# How can Spring be configured to ignore SSL Certificate validity

Tags: spring-mvc, ssl, tomcat

We have a fleet of deployed gateway devices that have a self-signed certificate that they use to make an HTTPS post to our Spring on Tomcat app. This certificate expired, and we cannot issue an update unless we can connect (Catch-22). We need to temporarily ignore the validity of the client SSL certificate in order to get operational again.

We have been trying to figure out where in the Spring XML to put the bean configuration (TrustManager class) to ignore SSL certificate validity.

We are desperate for help. This is not Spring Boot, but Spring MVC secured by spring security using old school XML configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Would not requiring a client certificate help? If so, in <tomcat>/conf/server.xml look for <Connector clientAuth="want"...> and set it to false.